# ERB -- content_for_with_default

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

I am trying to reduce the repetitive code with the following pattern in an ERB template:

```
<% if content_for(some_key) %>
  <%= yield(some_key) %>
<% else %>
  Some default values here
<% end %>
```

I've tried defining the following method in `ApplicationHelper` but understandably it's not working as expected;

```
def content_for_with_default(key, &block)
  if content_for?(key)
    yield(key)
  else
    block.call
  end
end
```

Here's how I'm trying to use it:

```
<%= content_for_with_default(some_key) do %>
  Some default values here
<% end %>
```

How can I write the `content_for_with_default` helper so that it has the intended effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your helper should be like this:

```
def content_for_with_default(key, &block)
  if content_for?(key)
    content_for(key)
  else
    capture(&block)
  end
end
```

EDIT: difference between `capture(&block)` and `block.call`

After the erb file is compiled, the block will be some ruby code like this:

```
');@output_buffer.append=  content_for_with_default('some_key') do @output_buffer.safe_concat('
');
@output_buffer.safe_concat('  Some default values here
'); end
```

You see, the strings within the block are concatenated to the output_buffer and `safe_concate` returns the whole output_buffer.

As a result, `block.call` also returns the whole output_buffer. However, `capture(&block)` creates a new buffer before calling the block and only returns the content of the block.

Comment: What's the difference between `capture(&block)` and `block.call` ?